# primeng calendar - display in client timezone

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng

Using `p-calendar` datetime selector, how can you display UTC stored dates in the client's timezone?

I logged the value using `onSelect` and it shows this:

`Mon Dec 04 2017 14:17:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

And then when I send the value to the DB, it converts to UTC, which is totally fine, however, say I refresh the page and display the value in the `p-calendar` element, it's displaying `Mon Dec 04 2017 19:17:00` (UTC).

I poured through [the docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) and found no mention of timezone whatsoever. It seems odd that it would consider the timezone while selecting, but not when loading from storage.

In my package.json, I am selecting `"primeng": "^4.3.0"`.

The app I'm creating is to be used globally, so the time should always be shown in the client's timezone.

Comment: I suggest you to implement third part library such as this very good one: https://momentjs.com

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out... also realized I left out a bunch of details that were involved.

Using Typescript, the field in question was of type Date. When the fetch was mapped to this field, it instanced a new Date object that by default applied my browser's timezone. Good one to realize. So where the value was `Mon Dec 04 2017 14:17:00 (UTC)`, the Date object created from that was `Mon Dec 04 2017 14:17:00 GMT-0500` : no time shift, just took the value as is and applied my timezone.

So to solve my problem, I had to shift the date values over to a new Date instance where I explicitly set the timezone to UTC. `p-calendar` took care of the rest and converted it to my current timezone for display.

Comment: Please could you provide an example on how you did this? :)

Answer (score 3):

you can specify `[utc]=true` like following

```
   <p-calendar ... [utc]='true'></p-calendar>
```

**EDIT**

Watch out, [utc] has been deprecated since then, see http://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5853. Only use it with old PrimeNg versions.

Comment: [utc] has been deprecated since then https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5853

Comment: This solution was valid for `"primeng": "4.3.0"`. Now One year already, primeng has grown a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To change timezone for displayed date in calendar you can just change timezone for `Date` object itself like this:

```
const newTimezoneDate = new Date (oldTimezoneDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'}));
```

and then just init calendar with new `Date` object

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: 
the date you selected in calendar is 2017-12-04 14:07:00 GMT-0500. 
when save it to database, the method JSON.stringify() will be invoked. For datetime property(e.g. billDate), it will call this.billDate.toISOString().
the method 'toISOString()' will change the datetime to '2017-12-07T19:07:00Z', so database value added 5 hours!!!

Solution: overide Date.toISOString(), in main.js, excuete the codes below will be ok.

```
  Date.prototype.toIsoString = function() {
    var tzo = -this.getTimezoneOffset(),
    dif = tzo >= 0 ? '+' : '-',
    pad = function(num) {
        var norm = Math.floor(Math.abs(num));
        return (norm < 10 ? '0' : '') + norm;
    };
    return this.getFullYear() +
     '-' + pad(this.getMonth() + 1) +
     '-' + pad(this.getDate()) +
     'T' + pad(this.getHours()) +
     ':' + pad(this.getMinutes()) +
     ':' + pad(this.getSeconds()) +
     dif + pad(tzo / 60) +
     ':' + pad(tzo % 60);
  }

  var dt = new Date();
  console.log(dt.toIsoString());
```